# White gap and blurry text after opening Mmenu

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I'm trying to use the mmenu plugin in my website. With the so so knowledge it works out quite well, except one thing. When i give the nav (hamburger) button a replace eg.: to bottom or position: fixed, and touch the button the menu shows well, but the website content gives a white gap or blurs my text now and then and only in Firefox' mobile app.

I also tried to give another button, which is already fixed, the same target, but then i also get a white gap.

Again, its only in Firefox' mobile app (Chrome and android browser is doing well). On Firefox desktop it shows well too.

When i keep it standard, at top left (position: absolute), everything is fine.

Hope there is a solution, otherwise i have to live with it. If you want i can add a screenshot.

P.s. im using off-canvas

Comment: Well so far i couldn't find any solution unfortunately. I read a lot and the problem might be "Transform". Anyhow maybe the creator or other mmenu guru could work on an option to fix the menu 'hamburger' button, it would be quite functional for mobile users though. A fixed button is possible, but the content is not viewing right.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but things still haven't been fixed.

The original site (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) has the same problem in firefox for android (just the stable version, not the beta version). The owner also tried to solve it, but has an iphone, so no problem.

AFAIK the problem only happens when you scroll a little downwards and open the off-canvas menu in firefox for android, so perhaps there is a bug in this app. When i switch to "show website in desktop mode" everything is fine. I hope someone has a clue, cause I seriously don't know what to do.

Edit: On my 10" tablet everything is fine. So it's only a problem on android phones.